# How to use utopia for normal texts, while use kpfonts for italic and math formulas?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

```latex
% Set kpfonts globally
\usepackage{kpfonts}
```

```latex
% Specify the utopia font for some texts
{\fontfamily{put} text text....}
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying the `{\fontfamily ...}` every time I want to use it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the contents of `t1jkp.fd` and replace the upright fonts with `put`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

% load t1jkp.fd here
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{jkp}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{n}{<-> jkpmn8t}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{sc}{<-> jkpmsc8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{scsl}{<-> jkpmscsl8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{it}{<-> jkpmit8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{sl}{<-> jkpmsl8t}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{n}{<-> jkpbn8t}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{sc}{<-> jkpbsc8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{scsl}{<-> jkpbscsl8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{it}{<-> jkpbit8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{sl}{<-> jkpbsl8t}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{n}{<-> jkpbxn8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{it}{<-> jkpbxit8t}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{sc}{<-> jkpbxsc8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{scsl}{<-> jkpbxscsl8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{sl}{<-> jkpbxsl8t}{}
% use Utopia
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{n}{<-> putr8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{m}{sc}{<-> putrc8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{n}{<-> putb8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{b}{sc}{<-> putbc8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * jkp/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{jkp}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * jkp/b/sc}{}


\begin{document}

test \fontname\font

\textit{test \fontname\font}

\textbf{test \fontname\font}

\textit{\textbf{test \fontname\font}}

\textsc{test \fontname\font}

\end{document}
```

[image]